# What is the meaning of the construction in array initialization?

Tags: java

I was solving tasks and saw a construction like that:

```
String t[] = new String[n], e;
```

Can you help me, what does ", e" mean? Wasn't able to find something about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a way to declare 2 variables without specifying the type `String` twice. For example this declares x and y with values 5 and 6:

```
int x = 5, y = 6;
```

In your case, t is declared as String array with value assigned as `new String[n]`, and `e` is a String (no value assigned) so it needs to be assigned before you reference `e` later.

IMO it is much clearer to specify on separate lines with brackets before the variable name:

```
String[] t = new String[n];
String e;
```

Note also that moving `[]` before `t` changes the definition of `e` to `String[]` such that `String [] t = new String[n], e` is equivalent to:

```
String[] t = new String[n];
String[] e;
```

Comment: I'm scouring the java spec to understand *why* `e` is a `String` and not a `String[]`. Does someone have a link to that at hand?

Comment: If you move the brackets both will be String[] in this: `String [] t = new String[n], e`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca A similar example is presented in [JLS 17, 10.2 Array Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2), so maybe you can use that as a starting point (I don't want to spend more time researching this esoteric abomination ;)). It looks like that section does indeed define it, but I don't have the energy for a close read.

Comment: would String[] t[] indicate a 2d array?

Comment: @experiment unit 1998X Yes that would declare `String[][] t`, and `String[] e`